# Go client SDK: check if a Deployment is fully ready

Tags: kubernetes

Say I have an in-memory Deployment object, what is the correct way of testing if it is fully ready? (not in the progress of rollout, upgrade or rollback).

Comment: I don't understand why this question was down voted by some people. What's the problem?

Comment: see the  `kubectl  rollout status ` source code https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/staging/src/k8s.io/kubectl/pkg/polymorphichelpers/rollout_status.go#L59

Answer (score 1):

I can't comment, so it will have to be an answer.

---

I don't think there is a ***right way*** of doing this, as it depends on a number of variables. Such as what languages you are proficient with etc.

Where I work, we run a `kubectl get pods` and grep the information that is relevant (in this case if the pod is available (ready) or not. This is all run through `bash` as part of a startup script:

```
function not_ready_count() {
  kubectl ${1} get pods -o json | jq -r '.items[].status.conditions[].status' | grep False | wc -l | awk '{ print $1 }'
}

function not_running_count() {
  kubectl ${1} get pods -o json | jq -r '.items[].status.phase' | grep -v Running | wc -l | awk '{ print $1 }'
}

function wait_until_running_and_ready() {
  sleep 2
  while [[ "$(not_running_count ${1})" != "0" ]]; do
    echo "waiting for $(not_ready_count ${1}) pods to start"
    sleep 3
  done
  while [[ "$(not_ready_count ${1})" != "0" ]]; do
    echo "waiting for $(not_ready_count ${1}) status probes to pass"
    sleep 3
  done
  sleep 2
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Following is my implementation to check if a deployment is Ready using `client-go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "flag"
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"

    metav1 "k8s.io/apimachinery/pkg/apis/meta/v1"
    "k8s.io/client-go/kubernetes"
    "k8s.io/client-go/tools/clientcmd"
    "k8s.io/client-go/util/homedir"
)

func main() {
    var kubeconfig *string
    if home := homedir.HomeDir(); home != "" {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", filepath.Join(home, ".kube", "config"), "(optional) absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    } else {
        kubeconfig = flag.String("kubeconfig", "", "absolute path to the kubeconfig file")
    }
    flag.Parse()

    config, err := clientcmd.BuildConfigFromFlags("", *kubeconfig)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    clientset, err := kubernetes.NewForConfig(config)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    deploymentsClient := clientset.AppsV1().Deployments("my-namespace")
    deploy, err := deploymentsClient.Get(context.Background(), "my-deploy", metav1.GetOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    if deploy != nil &&
        deploy.Spec.Replicas != nil &&
        *deploy.Spec.Replicas == deploy.Status.ReadyReplicas {
        fmt.Println("Deployment is READY")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("Deployment is NOT READY")
    }
}
```